# C# Data generator for Oracle: ORA-26010

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am trying to create a C# data generator for oracle database. Though I have run into some problems. I am getting ORA-26010 error message which is:

> A column which is NOT NULL in the database is not being loaded and will cause every row to be rejected.

I didn't have that problem with previous tables and spend hours already to find solution.

This is how it looks in the code:

```
 private static DataTable BuildMagazynTable(int b)
    {
        var magazynTable = new DataTable();
        magazynTable.Columns.Add("ID");
        magazynTable.Columns.Add("NAZWA_MAGAZYNU");
        magazynTable.Columns.Add("MIASTO");
        magazynTable.Columns.Add("ULICA");
        magazynTable.Columns.Add("NR_LOKALU");

        for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
        {
            var ar = magazynTable.NewRow();
            ar["ID"] = null;
            ar["NAZWA_MAGAZYNU"] = "Nazwa Magazynu" + i;
            ar["MIASTO"] = "Miasto" + i;
            ar["ULICA"] = "Ulica" + i;
            ar["NR_LOKALU"] = "Nr lokalu" + i;

            magazynTable.Rows.Add(ar);
        }
        return magazynTable;
    }
```

And there is how I created the table in oracle database:

```
CREATE TABLE magazyn (

id                NUMBER GENERATED by default on null as IDENTITY,
Nazwa_magazynu  VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
miasto            VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
ulica             VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
Nr_lokalu      VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE magazyn ADD CONSTRAINT magazyn_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id );
```

And there is screen from SQL Developer:
[image]

I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess with bulkcopy to send data to database.

Comment: Does it work if you omit the ID column from the DataTable?

Comment: ID is a Identity column, you shouldn't be passing any values to it, Null or not.

Comment: If i remove the ID i still get the same error  - 26010 on "NR_LOKALU" column, just like before. I have done same things with ID = null; on 3 diffrent tables and it worked fine. Just having problem on this one.

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is bigger than 9 then your data will fail as `Nazwa Magazynu10` has 16 characters and your column can only accommodate 15.

You can replicate the error in Oracle using:

```sql
INSERT INTO magazyn ( ID, NAZWA_MAGAZYNU, MIASTO, ULICA, NR_LOKALU )
SELECT NULL,
       'Nazwa Magazynu' || LEVEL,
       'Miasto' || LEVEL,
       'Ulica' || LEVEL,
       'Nr lokalu' || LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Which raises the error:

> ```
> ORA-12899: value too large for column  "SCHEMA_NAME"."MAGAZYN"."NAZWA_MAGAZYNU" (actual: 16, maximum: 15)
> ```

However, if you use shorter strings:

```sql
INSERT INTO magazyn ( ID, NAZWA_MAGAZYNU, MIASTO, ULICA, NR_LOKALU )
SELECT NULL,
       'NM' || TO_CHAR( LEVEL, 'FM00000' ),
       'M'  || TO_CHAR( LEVEL, 'FM00000' ),
       'U'  || TO_CHAR( LEVEL, 'FM00000' ),
       'NL' || TO_CHAR( LEVEL, 'FM00000' )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Then it works.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=650536f88dfd7e4e3ce43c63567a1ecb)*

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice that. Though it doesn't fix the main problem.